# Error installing passenger: passenger-6 from passenger requires libruby.so.2.5, but none of the providers can be installed

Tags: ruby, centos-8, passenger

Originally I wanted to update `ruby2.5` to `ruby2.7`.

However `passenger` hindered the update (yum threw an error), so I **removed** `passenger` and `ruby2.5` to install `ruby2.7` afterwards.

Installing `ruby2.7` then worked, however now **I cannot reinstall `passenger`**. (trying to outsmart an error just shifted it)

```
$ sudo yum -y install passenger

passenger                                                                        2.7 kB/s | 833  B     00:00
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package passenger-6.0.4-3.el8.x86_64 from epel requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package passenger-6.0.10-1.el8.x86_64 from passenger requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
    ...
  - package passenger-6.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 from passenger requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package passenger-6.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 from passenger requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
    ...
  - package passenger-6.0.9-1.el8.x86_64 from passenger requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package ruby-libs-2.5.5-105.module_el8.1.0+214+9be47fd7.x86_64 from appstream is filtered out by modular filtering
    ...
  - package ruby-libs-2.5.9-111.module_el8+475+35a6c697.x86_64 from appstream is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I removed the `passenger-repo` and reinstalled it without success, regarding the [official passenger documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/advanced_guides/install_and_upgrade/standalone/install/oss/el8.html).

To me, it seems something is *still sticking to* `ruby 2.5` here.

Can anyone help me?

---

My repositories:

```
appstream                    CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream
baseos                       CentOS Stream 8 - BaseOS
docker-ce-stable             Docker CE Stable - x86_64
docker-ce-test               Docker CE Test - x86_64
epel                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-next                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Next - x86_64
extras                       CentOS Stream 8 - Extras
extras-common                CentOS Stream 8 - Extras common packages
passenger                    passenger
powertools                   CentOS Stream 8 - PowerTools
remi-modular                 Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
remi-safe                    Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it doesn't help with your problem. You need to study better the packages involved and from which repository they arrive. Perhaps limiting your repositories to the minimum required for installing ruby and passenger may narrow the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a technology introduced in RHEL 8 (and later available in CentOS Linux/Stream 8) called modularity.  It allows the distribution to ship multiple version of the same packages, in the same repos, with only one set visible to the package manager at a time.  This is likely how you upgraded from ruby 2.5 to 2.7.

```
root@c8-container:~# dnf module list ruby
Last metadata expiration check: 1:39:02 ago on Tue Jan  2 23:51:04 2024.
CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream
Name    Stream     Profiles     Summary                                               
ruby    2.5 [d]    common [d]   An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language  
ruby    2.6        common [d]   An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language  
ruby    2.7        common [d]   An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language  
ruby    3.0        common [d]   An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language  
ruby    3.1        common       An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language  

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

That `[d]` by the 2.5 means that dnf will by default only see the packages from the `ruby:2.5` module stream.  The packages from the other module streams are filtered out.  If you opt-in to one of the other module streams like `ruby:2.7`, dnf will only see those packages and filter out everything else, including the default ones from `ruby:2.5`.

It works well enough if you limit yourself to packages shipped by the distribution, but quickly falls apart when you add third party repos, of which you have several enabled.  Modularity has a critical design flaw that you can only have dependencies between modules that were built in the same build system, and non-modular packages can only have dependencies on modular packages from default streams.  In this case, it means that passenger from the EPEL or passenger repos is built against the default version of ruby 2.5.  That is what error messages like this are telling you:

```
  - package passenger-6.0.4-3.el8.x86_64 from epel requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
```

Because passenger requires libruby.so.2.5, if the `ruby:2.5` module stream is filtered out then passenger becomes uninstallable, which is what this part of the error message is telling you:

```
  - package ruby-libs-2.5.9-111.module_el8+475+35a6c697.x86_64 from appstream is filtered out by modular filtering
```

Your best option is switch back to the `ruby:2.5` module stream so that third packages packages will work.  You can do this by uninstalling all ruby packages, switching to `ruby:2.5`, and then reinstalling the ruby packages you need.

```
dnf erase ruby\*
dnf module switch-to ruby:2.5
dnf install ruby passenger
```

Comment: Incredible. I would have never ever figured that out. Makes absoluteley sense.